# Rules for Inbound Mail Processing (multiple addresses? searches?)

Tags: email, activities

We'd like to use inbound mail processing with a bit more granularity so we can do a post-processing search that will let us easily tag new or updated constituents as YOUTH or ADULT.

Currently, we bcc: inbound@ourdomain.org and the new or updated records are created. However, we need to inspect each inbound email to understand if the contact should be tagged youth or adult.

I don't think we can have two inbound email addresses...if we can, I'd love to know how.

I thought maybe I could do something like use inbound+1@ourdomain.org (for youth) and inbound+2@ourdomain.org (for adults). This does result in the email and the +1 or +2 flag coming in to Civi!  However, I don't see a way to isolate what we need.  For example:

An advanced search for CONTACTS with an INBOUND EMAIL ACTIVITY has a check box for with/added by/assigned, but does not have a place to provide the address of inbound+1@ourdomain.org. If it did, I think this would give me a list of contacts that I would tag as youth.

Another option is an advanced for CONTACTS with INBOUND EMAIL ACTIVITY that contains "inbound+1@ourdomain.org". But I don't think the address shows in the activity records.

Another work-around I thought of is to include a distinct "code" in the emails we write and bcc to inbound@ourwebsite.org. For example, I could put +*+y after my sig file when I know I'm writing to a youth and then do an advanced search for CONTACTS that have INBOUND EMAIL ACTIVITIES containing +*+y in the body of the inbound email.  This would work but seems *way* too complicated.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this process. Thanks!

We're Wordpress 4.7 and CiviCRM 4.7.17.

Answer (score 1):

What you're requesting is possible by writing a custom extension, or possibly with CiviRules.

I managed the creation of such an extension, which is [available on Github](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.inemailclsfn).  This extension changes the activity type of any inbound email sent to `inbound+support@example.org` to a different activity type.

If you're a coder, you can adapt that extension to your purpose.  If not, try using CiviRules with a trigger of "when an activity is created" and conditions that match your inbound email, and an action of "add a tag".

Comment: I'll look at your code, thanks. I did have a look at CiviRules. Setting a condition "on inbound email"  is easy, but I can't see how to further define the condition to being "from inbound+1@mywebsite.com". Did you also conclude CiviRules cannot handle this type of delineation as to what it's ingesting when the +1 type addresses are used? Thanks.